# Data in textbox doesn't exists in the database then display message

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a C# windows forms application. It has a form with the following fields:

- `textboxRegistrationID`,
- `TextboxDate`,
- `TextboxName`,
- `TextBoxGender` and
- `TextBoxContactNumber`

with three buttons `GetData`, `Save` and `Exit`.

In the database I am having a `table` with the name `info` with five fields:

- `RegistrationID`,
- `Date`,
- `Name`,
- `Gender` and `ContactNumber` respectively.

When I save the data, it saves respectively and when I try to get the data from the database using `RegistrationID`, it will give the data if the `RegistrationID` **exists**. If it doesn't exist, it **throws** an error, saying *column doesn't exists*.

Now what I want is, instead of the `Error`, I want a message to be displayed saying *Registration Number Doesn't Exists*.

How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Comment: might be your your datatable or dataset is empty when registrationId  doesn't exists, please check for it first and then retrieve data from datatable or dataset

Comment: Did u use get and set property for each fields.

Comment: what exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: Share your code what you have done so far???

Comment: If you can show your code then we can help you.

Comment: con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Info where RegistrationID = '" + RegistrationID.Text + "'", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                RegistrationID.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                Date.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                Name.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                Gender.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                ContactNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                con.Close();   This is code i have used

Comment: Yes when data is present in database it will show all the data

Comment: @Mohammed Please mark an answer as accepted, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention your code according to that you can `count` `rows` of `datatable`

here is the code

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
      //display your data
} 

else
{
    // show your message here
}
```

if you have any problem then let me know.

**Note:- Here `dt` is your `DataTable` variable**

Comment: You are Well Come.

Comment: con.Open(); SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Info where RegistrationID = '" + RegistrationID.Text + "'", con); DataTable dt = new DataTable(); sda.Fill(dt); If(dt.Rows.Count > 0){ RegistrationID.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(); Date.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString(); Name.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString(); Gender.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString(); ContactNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString();}else{MessageBox.Show("Invalid Registration ID");} con.Close();      Yesterday this code worked but don't know what happened its not working now please help where it is wrong

Comment: Sorry not working now, even when i give a correct RegistrationID then also it is going to else block

Comment: Don't have any idea what is wrong with your code but try to dispose DataTable and SqlConnection and see what happen.

Comment: There was a small change in code so it didn't worked but the above code worked fine. thank you kinjal patel

Comment: You are Well Come.

Comment: Kinjal Patel can i ask you one more question, its regarding Crystal report column size ... can i ask?

Comment: well all i can say is that i can try it but not sure that i can solve it, but yes you can ask.

Comment: I am working on C# windows form application, it has five fields namely ID, NAME, CONTACTNUMBER, EMAIL AND DESCRIPTION (MultiLine) and in database it has respectively fields, while saving data in database for Description field i use newline(next line) like below:
for, ID-901
    {XYZ,
    1st, STREET,
    CITYNAME.}
In database it will save in single line but when i try print using crystal report then it will print same as here    {XYZ,
    1st, STREET,
    CITYNAME.}  but when the Description fields extends more than 5-6 lines then the details will overlap in next columns

Comment: if you can give send me a test mail to my email id mkmohammedkhadir@gmail i will send you the images of how it will print and what i want, if it is feasible for you

Comment: its ok i got your problem just give me some time and i'll get back to you on this

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch the data from the database, say in a DataSet ds; check following things

```
ds != null;
ds.Tables.Count > 0;
ds.Tables[0] != null;
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0;
```

If any of the above condition turns out to be true; display

```
MessageBox.Show("Record doesn't exist!!!")
```

Else, display the results

**Update**

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open(); 
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Info where RegistrationID = '" + RegistrationID.Text + "'", con); 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
    sda.Fill(dt); 
    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count() > 0)
    {
        RegistrationID.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(); 
        Date.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString(); 
        Name.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString(); 
        Gender.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString(); 
        ContactNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString(); 
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data does not exist!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: con.Open(); SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Info where RegistrationID = '" + RegistrationID.Text + "'", con); DataTable dt = new DataTable(); sda.Fill(dt); RegistrationID.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString(); Date.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString(); Name.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString(); Gender.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString(); ContactNumber.Text = dt.Rows[0][4].ToString(); con.Close(); This is the code i have used and data will be displayed when data is present

Comment: Try the code under Update and let me know if that is what you are looking for